# Haskell IO Monad in ST Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I guess I have a simple problem, but I'm not able to solve it:
I want to create a vector, call FFI on this vector and return it.

```Haskell
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable as VSM
withCarray :: Int -> (Ptr Float -> IO ()) -> (Vector Float)
withCarray n f = VS.create $ do
  v <- VSM.new n 
  VSM.unsafeWith v f
  return v
```

Now, VSM.unsafeWith returns an IO, and this is in the ST Monad. But if I use ioToST or liftIO I get the following problem:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘RealWorld’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall s. ST s (VSM.MVector s Float)
        at src/Interpolation.hs:(60,30)-(63,10)
      Expected type: ST s (VSM.IOVector Float)
        Actual type: ST s (VSM.MVector (PrimState (ST s)) Float)
```

Any idea, how I can convert the `unsafeWith` to the correct Monad? I saw that IO and ST are both Prim-Monads, so it should be possible to convert them, right?

Comment: The function you seem to be looking for is [`unsafeIOToST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeIOToST). Whether this is remotely sensible depends heavily on what your FFI is actually doing, and I'm too sleepy right now to even guess whether it might be reasonable in the context of your code.

Comment: Basically, if "call FFI on this vector" as about any sort of I/O, then you shouldn't be doing that. If it's just implementing a pure function in C, then what you're attempting may be reasonable.

Comment: In general you can not convert between `IO` and `ST`. Inside `IO`, you can perform anything (e.g. sending an email, launching missiles, ...) while `ST` guarantees that no I/O is performed except for mutating `ST` references and vectors. If you are sure that the FFI call is not doing anything  (including reading from disk/network) beyond mutating the vector, then `unsafeIOToST` can be used. Calling such an unsafe function puts the burden on you to verify this is the case.

Comment: The ST monad deliberately works to forbid you from what you're trying to do, because IO can have arbitrary side effects and ST isn't supposed to have any.  If _you_ know that it has no side effects, then an unsafe conversion may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For FFI applications, it's usually simplest not to bother with `ST` at all and do everything in `IO`. If you must have a pure interface (and your FFI function actually is pure in the way needed), you can call [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) to give a pure interface.

However, I think I would shy away from writing `withCarray` as you have done here. Abstraction is nice, but this is too easy to accidentally misuse by passing a not-suitably-behaving callback. If you must have it, at the very least name it `unsafeWithCarray` and leave a Haddock explicitly stating under what circumstances it is safe.

Comment: Or `unsafeDupablePerformIO`, when appropriate. That's closer to `runST`. But of course extra care is required!